# Data relationship from Query

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm trying to run a query on my Firestore to get all the products available on a specific city. I have a `stores` collection with a property called `city` and a subcollection called `products`.

My idea was to query it and then access the subcollection for each item, but I'm having a hard time doing that.

Here is what I have so far:

```
getProducts() {
   this.db.collection('stores', ref => ref.where('city', '===', 'New York').limit(10))
      .snapshotChanges().pipe(
         map(snaps => {
            snaps.map(snap => {
               const id = { id: snap.payload.doc.id };
               this.db.collection(`stores/${id.id}/products/`).snapshotChanges().pipe(
                  map({
                     productSnaps => {
                        productSnaps.map(productSnap => {
                            return productSnap.payload.doc.data() as Product;
                        })
                     }
                  })
               )
            })
         })
      )
}
```

With this I'm getting an array of 10 Observables, so I can't really do anything with the data.

This is the console log:

> [Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable] (10)

Thank you!

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen it's returning an array with 10  observables object but I can't really do anything with it. `[Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable] (10)` I can't access the data

Comment: For sure I will do that... Oh no :( Hopefully we can get this sorted, if I get anything here I'll mention you on the answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried replicating your data model:

[image]

[image]

Here is my solution (I am using Node.js) to get all the products that belong to a document in stores collection that has City = New York:

```
let collRef = db.collection('stores').where('city', '==',
  'New York').limit(2);

let query1 = collRef.get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      console.log('No matching documents.');
      return;
    }

    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        db.collection('stores').doc(doc.id).collection('products').get().then(
            snapshot => {snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
            }
        )});

    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });
```

and the result:

[image]